# Outlier detection algorithm: Datasets lumped together or separated?

Tags: outliers, biostatistics

Say, I have two groups of human subjects; groupA and groupB, with a size of nA and nB, respectively.
Then, I do the same measurement on both groups (it is actually some results from a CFD simulation); datasetA and datasetB.

I know it is recommended to do one's best to not remove any data, but I want to detect my outliers from the datasets. The end goal is to see if the two datasets are statistically different.

Now my question is if I have to mix both datasets datasetA and datasetB together and then carry out the desired outlier algorithm on the lumped dataset or I have to run one algorithm for each of the datasets separately?

Please, support your answer with a reference, if possible please.

Comment: If you combine datasets you should keep track of which group is which. Depending on your software that might mean creating a new column or variable as an  identifier before you combine. Then all depends: it might be true that the groups are complementary and what looks like an outlier in one group is not so surprising in the context of the other group. There can't be a universal recipe here and you need to bring in substantive knowledge of whether the groups are expected to be similar or different. If you know in advance that there might be a difference, your group identifier is essential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two datasets are indeed statistically different, then mixing would be a bad idea. Consider two extreme scenarios:

1. Say observations in $A$ come from $N(0,1)$ and observations in $B$ come from $N(5,1)$. Now an observation of $5$ in $A$ is clearly an outlier prior to mixing and not after. So by removing outliers from the mixed set, you will miss some outliers.
2. Say $n_B>n_A$ by a considerable margin. So the distribution of the combined set is more inclined towards $N(5,1)$. If the difference in number of observations is considerably different then an observation of, say, $-1.5$ may be detected as an outlier in the combined set while it ought not to be.

On the other hand if the two sample sets do come from the same distribution then of course combining the data increases observations and therefore the accuracy of estimates of the underlying distribution.

Overall, you should try both while keeping the above points in mind and depending on what results you get from testing the two distribution for statistical difference, take a call.

Comment: That makes a complete sense, Thanks

Comment: @Nick Cox sorry it might be a dumb question, but I am not familiar with statistical terms. What does N(x,y) means in your response?

Comment: $N(0,1)$ refers to the Normal probability distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

Comment: It's not my answer; it comes from @Dayne; I edited it only. But $N(5, 1)$ usually means for example a normal distribution with mean 5 and variance 1. Sometimes it means with SD 1. All that is implied is that the distributions **might** be very different.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! :-)